# EAS Build with EAS Updates – handling environmental variables

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm having troubles handling environmental variables, hence I'd like to ask what's the best way to manage them when using EAS Build and EAS Update services.

My project has three main files when I'm somehow referencing environmental variables:

**`app.config.ts`**

```
import 'dotenv/config';

const runtimeVersion = '1.0.0';
const version = '1.0.0';

const EASProjectId = 'my-eas-project-id';
const scheme = 'com.myapp.mobile';

export default {
  expo: {
    name: 'MyApp',
    slug: 'MyApp',
    owner: 'myapp',
    version,
    orientation: 'portrait',
    icon: './assets/icon.png',
    userInterfaceStyle: 'light',
    scheme,
    runtimeVersion,
    experiments: {
      tsconfigPaths: true,
      typedRoutes: true
    },
    updates: {
      enabled: true,
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0,
      checkAutomatically: 'ON_ERROR_RECOVERY',
      url: `https://u.expo.dev/${EASProjectId}`,
    },
    plugins: [
      'expo-router',
      ['expo-updates', {
        username: 'myexpousername',
      }],
    ],
    splash: {
      image: './assets/splash.png',
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: [
      '**/*',
    ],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: false,
      bundleIdentifier: 'com.myapp.mobile',
      infoPlist: {
        UIBackgroundModes: [
          'location',
          'fetch',
          'remote-notification',
        ],
      },
      config: {
        usesNonExemptEncryption: false,
      },
    },
    web: {
      favicon: './assets/favicon.png',
    },
    extra: {
      eas: { projectId: EASProjectId },
      API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
    },
  },
};
```

**`eas.json`**

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.17.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      },
      "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "development"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "node": "18.17.0",
      "channel": "staging",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "APP_PROFILE": "preview",
        "APP_CHANNEL": "staging",
        "API_URL": "https://staging.api.myapp.com"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "node": "18.17.0",
      "channel": "production",
      "distribution": "store",
      "env": {
        "APP_PROFILE": "production",
        "APP_CHANNEL": "production",
        "API_URL": "https://api.myapp.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

**`.env`**

```
API_URL=https://staging.api.myapp.com
```

I'm using a prebuilt version of the project when developing and running it with `expo run:ios`. It all works as expected.

I'm also building it with `eas build --profile preview --platform ios`, and the build indeed works as expected.

But then, I'm using `eas update --channel staging --platform ios`, and my app complains about the lack of `API_URL`.

**I have one main question – what's the best way to handle environmental variables when using EAS Build and EAS Update?** Ideally, the proposed way would work when I'm building both `preview` and `production` profiles (where the env vars might be different).

PS I went through Expo's documentation, and found it really confusing, hence the post here.

Answer (score 0):

This is my used environment separation structure in my Expo projects

In eas.json

```
{
  ...
  "build": {
    "development": {
      ...
      "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "development"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
       ...
       "env": {
        "APP_ENV": "staging"
      }
  ...
}
```

In app.config.js

```
module.exports = () => {
   const config =
      process.env.APP_ENV === "development"
         ? require("./app.development.json")
         : process.env.APP_ENV === "staging"
         ? require("./app.staging.json")
         : require("./app.production.json");

   config.expo.version = "1.0.0";
   //You can change it some expo parameters, not only the version

   return config;
};
```

I have 3 app.[environmen].json files.
(Environment can to be [development, staging, production]) here

```
{
  "expo": {},
  ...
  "extra": {
    API_URL: "myxy.url",
    MY_OTHER_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE: true
  }
}
```

If you need additional environments, you can add them at any time

Answer (score 0):

I am using an expo app with different app variants **[staging, production]**.

This is my **eas config**

```
 "staging": {
      "distribution": "store",
      "env": {
        "APP_VARIANT": "staging"
      },
      "channel": "staging",
      "autoIncrement": true
  },
  "production": {
      "channel": "production",
      "autoIncrement": true
  }
```

And my **app.config.ts** is something like this

```
export default ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => {
  const isStaging = process.env.APP_VARIANT === 'staging';

  const productionConfig: ExpoConfig = {
    ...config,
    name: 'App',
    ios: {
      bundleIdentifier: 'com.xxxx.influencer',
    },
    android: {
      package: 'com.xxxx.influencer',
    },
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: '8c24d46b-xxxx-45f1-xxxx-xxx571c7xxxx',
      },
      GQL_URL: 'https://gql.xxxx.com/graphql/',
    },
    updates: {
      url: 'https://u.expo.dev/xxx-xxxx-45f1-9379-dce571cxxx',
    },
    runtimeVersion: {
      policy: 'appVersion',
    },
  };

  if (isStaging) {
    return {
      ...productionConfig,
      name: '(Stg)App',
      ios: {
        ...productionConfig.ios,
        bundleIdentifier: 'com.xxxx.influencer.staging',
      },
      android: {
        ...productionConfig.android,
        package: 'com.xxxx.influencer.staging',
      },
      extra: {
        ...productionConfig.extra,
        GQL_URL: 'https://stg-gql.xxxx.com/graphql/',
      },
    };
  }

  return productionConfig;
};
```

For building the app (for staging) I use these commands

```
eas build --profile staging --platform android
eas build --profile staging --platform ios
```

Till this point, everything works fine. The build can properly set all environment variable, as I have specified the profile with `env` on my eas.json.

Also on the app.config.ts, it can pickup the correct env[staging].

**The problem happens with the eas update!**

I was trying to push update on my staging variant with the following command

```
eas update --branch staging --message "Message..."
```

Although I was sending the update to the staging branch, the new update wasn't able to pick the `APP_VARIANT` correctly. Probably, it was undefined on `app.config.ts` and my staging app was behaving like the production app by using my production `GQL_URL: 'https://gql.xxxx.com/graphql/',` endpoint.

Finally, I was able to fix that by setting the `APP_VARIANT` with the eas update command like this

```
APP_VARIANT=staging eas update --branch staging --message "Message..."
```

On the CI, it will be something like this

```
APP_VARIANT=staging npx eas-cli update --branch staging --message="`git log -1 --pretty=%B`" --non-interactive
```